# confused about theads schedule of SCHED_FIFO policy when threads have same priority

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel

I created two threads ThreadA and ThreadB in main thread, and three threads   have the same Priority. the order of call is ThreadA in front of ThreadB(I can't understand).
　　However, the order of call is ThreadB in front of ThreadA when increasing the priority main thread(I understanded).
I get this message from man page as follows:

  `A call to sched_setscheduler(2), sched_setparam(2), or sched_setattr(2)
  will  put  the SCHED_FIFO (or SCHED_RR) thread identified by pid at the
  start of the list if it was runnable.  As a consequence, it may preempt
  the  currently  running  thread  if it has the same priority.  (POSIX.1
  specifies that the thread should go to the end of the list.)`

Code as follows:

```
/*
 * critical.c
 *
 * compile with  gcc critical.c -o critical -lrt -lpthread
 *
 *  result is aaaaabbbbb when three thread have same priority 
 *  result is bbbbbaaaaa when main thread has higher priority 
 */

#include <pthread.h>    /* header file for pthreads */
#include <unistd.h>     /* header file for POSIX conformance */
#include <time.h>       /* header file for POSIX time management */
#include <sched.h>      /* header file for POSIX scheduling */
#include <stdio.h>      /* header file for standard input/outputlibrary */
#define _REENTRANT      /* macro to ensure system calls are reentrant */

void *threadA(void *);   /* predefine threadA routine */
void *threadB(void *);   /* predefine threadB routine */

pthread_t threadA_id,threadB_id,main_id;   /* thread identifiers */
pthread_attr_t attrA,attrB;        /* thread attribute structures */
struct sched_param param;          /* scheduling structure for thread attributes */

int policy=SCHED_FIFO;
int priority_min,priority_max;     /* for range of priority levels */

/* main routine */
int main()
{
  struct timespec start;
  int status;                        /* check that system calls return ok */

  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);        /* get the time   */
  printf("Start time is: %d seconds %d nano_seconds\n",start.tv_sec,start.tv_nsec);

  /* Set processor affinity */
  unsigned long mask = 1; /* use only 1 CPU core */
  unsigned int len = sizeof(mask);
  status = sched_setaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_setaffinity");
  status = sched_getaffinity(0, len, &mask);
  if (status < 0) perror("sched_getaffinity");

  /* Find priority limits */

  priority_max = sched_get_priority_max(policy);
  priority_min = sched_get_priority_min(policy);

  /* Change priority and policy of main thread */

  main_id = pthread_self();
  param.sched_priority=priority_min;
  status = pthread_setschedparam(main_id, policy, &param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam"); /* error check */

  /* Create threadA */

  param.sched_priority = priority_min;
  pthread_attr_init(&attrA);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrA,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrA,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadA_id, &attrA, threadA, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadA_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Create threadB */
  param.sched_priority = priority_min; /* so that B runs with a higher priority than A */
  pthread_attr_init(&attrB);
  status = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attrB,policy);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedpolicy"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attrB,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_attr_setschedparam"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_create(&threadB_id, &attrB, threadB, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_create"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_setschedparam(threadB_id,policy,&param);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_setschedparam");

  /* Join threads - force main to wait for the thread to terminate */
  printf("main() waiting for threads\n");

  status = pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadA_id, NULL)"); /* error check */
  status = pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL);
  if (status != 0) perror("pthread_join(threadB_id, NULL)"); /* error check */

  printf("\nmain() reporting that all threads have terminated\n");
  return(0);

}  /* end of main */

void *threadA(void *arg)
{
  int j;
  for(j=1;j<=5;j++){
    printf("a");                    
  }
  return (NULL);
}

void *threadB(void *arg)
{
  int j;
  for(j=1;j<=5;j++){
    printf("b");                     
  }
  return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: What *error* message do you get? I suggest to share your code, so we could see what might be the problem.

Comment: There is no error message,  I just can't understand the result.

Comment: I cannot compile your code. I don't have `librt`and my mac OS is apparently not that POSIX compliant. What output do you get? and what output do you expect?

Comment: BTW, you are currently running all your threads with same priority (`priority_min`).

Comment: Yes, I just want to learn scheduling policy.

Comment: result is aaaaabbbbb when three thread have same priority, and 
 result is bbbbbaaaaa when main thread has higher priority

Comment: [pthread_join](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libpthread/pthread.c?rev=1.134&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&only_with_tag=MAIN) is implemented with a `pthread_cond_wait`. And this thread has a higher priority. But why would it matter with regards to other two threads. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Example is to create a thread with FIFO scheduling at priority 1:

```
int retVal;
pthread_attr_t attr;
struct sched_param schedParam;
pthread_t thread;

retVal = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
if (retVal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_init error %d\n", retVal);
    exit(1);
}

retVal = pthread_attr_setinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED);
if (retVal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_setinheritsched error %d\n", retVal);
    exit(1);
}

retVal = pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(&attr, SCHED_FIFO);
if (retVal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_setschedpolicy error %d\n", retVal);
    exit(1);
}

schedParam.sched_priority = 1;
retVal = pthread_attr_setschedparam(&attr, &schedParam);
if (retVal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_attr_setschedparam error %d\n", retVal);
    exit(1);
}

retVal = pthread_create(&thread,
                        &attr,
                        _Thread,
                        NULL);    
if (retVal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create error %d\n", retVal);
    exit(1);
}
```

If your real-time priority soft limit is too restrictive.

Either call `ulimit -r unlimited` in shell before running your code. Or call `setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, ...)` directly in your code.

System-wide limits are set in `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: thank you, I chedked privileges. I just can't understand result of my code. Could you help me to explain this.